# How do you measure how "typical" a set of events are?

Tags: probability, distributions, expected-value, independence, combinatorics

Given a set of events and their probability of occuring, where they all add to 1. Edit: the set of events can be of any size, the example below is only A and B with 50/50 probabilities for simplicity of example.

Such as A=0.5 and B=0.5.

Given a group of events, where order doesn't matter:
Group 1: AAABBB
Group 2: AAAAAABBBBBB
Group 3: AABBBB
Group 4: AAAABBBBBBBB

Event groups 1 and 2 are 50% A, and 50% B. When I measure the probability of getting Group 1 vs Group 2, Group 2 is less likely because getting exactly 50/50 in 12 trials is lower than in 6 trials, because the possible combinations that aren't 50/50 goes up. But both are exactly the expected theoretical distribution. How would I measure how typical a distribution while being independent of sample size? Where the output for G1 = G2, and output for G3 = G4.

Comment: Order does matter because long strings of a particular letter may indicate some form of dependence.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, what he's saying is that these are unordered data. He's stating that as background information about the data generating mechanism, not asking whether or not order matters.

Comment: @gammer I am not sure. The OP says order doesn't matter.  It is not clear whether or not they are given as ordered.  The OP should clarify this.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, grammer is correct, assume the data is unordered. In the desired function, ABAB would be equivilant to AABB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are looking at only two possible event outcomes, $A$ and $B$, we can model the event outcome as a Bernoulli random variable, $X$, with parameter $p$. This $p$ is the probability of a "success", which we can define as the probability of event $A$. The occurrence of event $B$, is then a failure and this happens with probability $1-p$. In your example, you set $p=0.5$, but if you'd like to generalize it can take any value between $0$ and $1$.

To look at groups, you need to know the probability of the outcome for a series of Bernoulli trials. This is given by a Binomial distribution. For $n$ trials, the probability of $k$ successes ($A$'s) is given by:
$$P(X=k) = {n\choose k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}. $$

We can test this on your example groups.

Group 1 has probability 
$$ P(X=3) = {6\choose 3} (0.5)^3 (1-0.5)^{6-3} = 5/16$$

while Group 2 has probability
$$ P(X=6) = {12\choose 6} (0.5)^6 (1-0.5)^{12-6} = 231/1024$$

It seems that you are interested not in these count probabilities, but rather in the probabilities of seeing some proportion of event outcomes. There are several methods to find confidence intervals for these observed proportions as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval), but ultimately they will all depend on the sample size.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that the solution I'm looking for would be for an arbitrary number of events. Such as events, A=0.5, B=0.25, and C=0.25. I will update the question. Thank you for your response though!

Comment: If this answer suits for the case of two distinct event types, then the [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) may be what you are looking for.

Comment: @GeoMatt22 Sadly It doesn't work for the 2 case event. I am looking for a measure of how typical a distribution is. So, G1 and G2 should have the same result, since they are both exactly the expected theoretical distribution. Although I am unsure if what I'm looking for actually exists.

Comment: @AshtonHunger This is what I was trying to get at with my last paragraph. For G1 and G2 to give the same result you want a proportion, but the underlying distributions for the events depends on sample size. While you can approximate this proportion, it still depends on your number of samples. Sorry if I was unclear!

Comment: @AnnaBrodio I had actually missed the link on "here" in the last paragraph. That is looking much closer to what I am trying to achieve. That really helps point me in the right direction! Thank you!